# Is it possible to initialize a vector with increasing values in a single line?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Is it possible to merge the two initialization lines into a single statement with the help of initializer lists or other C++ features? The vector values always increment with one, but the size `n` is not fixed.

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 10;

    // Can the two lines below be combined into a single statement?
    std::vector<int> v(n);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

    for (int i : v)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you wan't it for any number of values?  In C++11 and above you can use `std::vector<int> v = {some set of numbers}`

Comment: The size can vary. I have made it more clear in the question.

Comment: We're not talking about using a self-written helper function, right?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have? It's clear and self-explanatory.

Comment: @Stasik: How can it be a duplicate when the answers there are the question here?

Comment: @Stasik No it is not, I ask whether it is possible to do it in a single line.

Comment: @Stasik: This question already uses `iota`, but asks whether new stuff in C++11 (or C++14) enables you to write `auto v = vec_range(1, 10, 1)`.

Comment: Yes they can. Just remove the carriage return symbol after `;` in the end of the `v` definition.

Comment: @Stasik this question seems to be about constructing the `vector` with increasing value, not setting it that way after construction. (Why? Who knows.)

Comment: @BoBTFish: To be fair, it would avoid zero-initialising all the elements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::back_inserter` etc. But then you probably want a call to `reserve(n)` as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. Nothing, I am just curious if it is possible, because always when I have coded something lately, there seems to be a more concise and elegant way of doing it in C++11 (or later).

Comment: @BoBTFish: Yeah and then you need to profile because you're doing something simple in a more complex way and it might confuse the optimiser for no reason

Comment: Well, yes, it's certainly possible. But I'm not going to enumerate all the fancy ways you could do it until you demonstrate a use case or an actual practical problem that you're facing. Until then, what you already have is just fine.

Comment: I bet you will not like it: `std::vector<int> a([n] () { std::vector<int> v(n); std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1); return v; } ());`

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Boost.counting_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) for this:

```
std::vector<int> v(boost::counting_iterator<int>(1),
                    boost::counting_iterator<int>(n + 1));
```

([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e946dc8017eb1c73)) Now whether this is worth it and easier to read than what you already have is for you to decide.

Comment: Given that boost isn't really a C++ "feature", this is almost a borderline answer. But then, again, it's boost.

Comment: It's as borderline as the question so :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: True. And OP can always put the original code in an inline function, if a boost dependency isn't OK. `inline std::vector<int> range(int count){ std::vector<int> v(count); std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);  return v; }`. Alternatively, as always, template magic.

Comment: @Zeta I usually don't have any qualms posting Boost answers to C++ questions. Even if OP does not use Boost, some future reader probably will. As you said, it's Boost. :)

Comment: I get a bit wary when the suggested library isn't header-only, but here you're fine.

Answer (score 9):

Not really, no. If `n` is a runtime variable, the best you could probably do is to just throw this in a function somewhere:

```
std::vector<int> ints(int n) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        v.push_back(n+1);
    }
    return v;
}

// now it's one line?
std::vector<int> v = ints(n);
```

If it's compile time, you can use `std::index_sequence` to provide an initializer list:

```
template <int... Is>
std::vector<int> ints(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...> ) {
    return std::vector<int>{ (Is+1)... };
}


template <int N>
std::vector<int> ints() {
    return ints(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{});
}
```

But either way, you need a helper function.