# print static variable for template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, template-meta-programming, static-variables

I have the following [template metaprogramming](https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/introduction-to-c-template-metaprogramming/) implementation of factorial:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n> struct factorial{
  static const int res = n*factorial<n-1>::res;
};

template <> struct factorial<0>{
  static const int res = 1;
};

int main(){
  std::cout << factorial<5>::res << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles successfully and outputs 120, as expected. However, for purely self-enjoying reasons, I would like to instead make it *not* compile, and instead display 120 in the error message of the compiler.

Is there a simple syntax mistake I can deliberately enter into my code to get it to fail to compile and yet still print the value of 5!, i.e. 120, in the compiler error message?

I anticipate that the answer will probably be compiler dependent; I am currently using g++ that came with Xcode Mac OSX, which iirc is a frontend for clang.

Comment: If you allow `-Werror`, this does it. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34dfcdcb110e9bc4 `static_assert` may be of help to if that's not cheating.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I guess after [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697980/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-vector-with-increasing-values-in-a-single-line/36698222#comment60984491_36698222) I can't quite get away with "might not be useful for OP". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the option `-Werror` is allowed or if warnings count as errors, this:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n> struct factorial{
  static const int res = n*factorial<n-1>::res;
};

template <> struct factorial<0>{
  static const int res = 1;
};

int main(){
  char x[factorial<5>::res];
  return x[sizeof(x)];
}
```

will produce the error/warning

> error: 'x[120ul]' is used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]

using gcc 5.3 or

> error: array index 120 is past the end of the array (which contains 120 elements) [-Werror,-Warray-bounds]

using clang 3.8.

Comment: This is great for displaying integers. I think for displaying a double (i.e. for template metaprogramming calculation of pi or something) I can just do something like 'static char c = x', which will print a warning if x is not a whole number

Comment: @xdavidliu I don't know how to do this for `double`s off the top of my head, and I'll go to sleep know. You can just post that as a follow up question, if no one answers, feel free to ping me here with a link and I'll think about it tomorrow. Your idea will probably just include the types, not the value, but see for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a declared, but undefined template to print out the value as a compile time error.

```
template<int n>
class display;

template<int n> struct factorial{
    static const int res = n*factorial<n-1>::res;
};

template<> struct factorial<0>{
    static const int res = 1;
};

int main()
{
    display<factorial<5>::res> value;
}
```

g++ outputs:

```
g++ -std=c++11 fact.cxx
fact.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
fact.cxx:14:29: error: aggregate ‘display<120> value’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  display<factorial<5>::res> value;
                             ^
```